# javascript object Assignment an array

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

i have an object and with specific key a assign an array

```
denemeobject['items'] = Object.values(
                  JSON.parse(results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray),
                );
```

problem is it looks like this :

```
"items": [
        [
          {
            "barcode": "1245124125412",
            "qty": 3
          },
          {
            "barcode": "1254123151231",
            "qty": 1
          },
          {
            "barcode": "2352341241241",
            "qty": 1
          },
          {
            "barcode": "1241251241254",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      ]
```

when i get data it comes to me in array. but assign to in object it caused it array in array. is that normal or there is something off

should be look like this :

```
[
    {
      "barcode": "1245124125412",
      "qty": 3
    },
    {
      "barcode": "1254123151231",
      "qty": 1
    },
    {
      "barcode": "2352341241241",
      "qty": 1
    },
    {
      "barcode": "1241251241254",
      "qty": 1
    }
  ]
```

how am i supposed to do that ? any ideas?

Comment: please share JSON string that you are trying to parse. also why are you using ```Object.Values```? any requirement for that. please share clear details to figure out the issue

Comment: First of all, I admit that there should be one array. However, what this ```JSON.parse(results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray)``` part actually returns? I don't know, but maybe it return an array + ```Object.values()```returns array to

Comment: {"BarcodeArray":[{"barcode":"1245124125412","qty":3},{"barcode":"1254123151231","qty":1},{"barcode":"2352341241241","qty":1},{"barcode":"1241251241254","qty":1}]}  this is the string and i want to use array part to add a new object @GyanendraSingh

Comment: Why is `results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray` a JSON string that itself represents on object that has a BarcodeArray property? Anyway, assuming the code is correct, you need `denemeobject['items'] = JSON.parse(results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray).BarcodeArray;` (because values() returns an array, another solution is to simply append `[0]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Object.values`, just dereference the `BarcodeArray` property.  You then have a plain array of objects containing `barcode` and `qty` properties, as you suggested you required.

```js
const data = `{"BarcodeArray":[{"barcode":"1245124125412","qty":3},{"barcode":"1254123151231","qty":1},{"barcode":"2352341241241","qty":1},{"barcode":"1241251241254","qty":1}]}`

console.log(JSON.parse(data).BarcodeArray)
```